# How to pass a string in the format <someText> in MailMessage.Body Property

Tags: c#

I need to pass some text in angular brackets like < head> or < script> in the `MsgBody` part, I am unable to do so... my code-

```
     MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
     msg.Body = string.Format("<b>System Area :</b>{0}<br /><b>Assigned To : </b>{1}<br /><b>Status :</b><font color=#0000FF>{2}</font><br /><br><b>Description :</b> {3}", system_Area, Assigned_ToVal, TaskStatus, MsgBody);
```

Comment: `msg.IsBodyHtml = true;`?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "I am unable to do so".

Comment: I need to pass some text in `MsgBody` which would have some texy in angular brackets... It gets treated as a HTML tag...

Comment: `IsBodyHtml`  is set to true

Comment: if you don't get the HTML deactivated ;) you can always revert to [character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Character_references) - for example `<` = `&lt;` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to HtmlEncode the desired text body and escape the entire string with "@":

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
string system_Area_Encoded = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(system_Area);
string assigned_ToVal_Encoded = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(Assigned_ToVal);
string taskStatus_Encoded = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(TaskStatus);
string msgBody_Encoded = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(MsgBody);
msg.Body = string.Format(@"<b>System Area :</b>{0}<br /><b>Assigned To : </b>{1}<br /><b>Status :</b><font color=#0000FF>{2}</font><br /><br><b>Description :</b> {3}", system_Area_Encoded, assigned_ToVal_Encoded, taskStatus_Encoded, msgBody_Encoded);
```

You can get more info about HtmlEncode in MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx